# how can i get fragments less than 3 length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i get fragments less than 3 length in this generator made with Python?

```
def codone(sequenza,frame):
    n = len(sequenza)
    for i in range(frame - 1, n - 2, 3 ):
        yield sequenza[i:i+3]

for i in range(1,4):
    print(list(codone(test,i)))
```

example

given the variable `test:"ACTGCAGCATCAGCCATGCAACT3"`
the desired output should be:

`['ACT', 'GCA', 'GCA', 'TCA', 'GCC', 'ATG', 'CAA', 'CT3']  ['CTG', 'CAG', 'CAT', 'CAG', 'CCA', 'TGC', 'AAC','T3']  ['TGC', 'AGC', 'ATC', 'AGC', 'CAT', 'GCA', 'ACT','3']`

Comment: Can you explain with an example - input and output?

Comment: What is `frame` for ?

Comment: @Austin have the test variable test = "ACTGCAGCATCAGCCATGCAACT3"                             
 and as an output I have this result :                                                                                                      
['ACT', 'GCA', 'GCA', 'TCA', 'GCC', 'ATG', 'CAA', 'CT3']
['CTG', 'CAG', 'CAT', 'CAG', 'CCA', 'TGC', 'AAC']
['TGC', 'AGC', 'ATC', 'AGC', 'CAT', 'GCA', 'ACT']                                                                       
the problem is that the generator doesn't show me the strings of less than 3 length and I need to visualize them

Comment: @azro frame frame is a value that I use to define the starting point of the output calculation

Comment: Please [edit] your post, add a example input and the expected output you want. Because regarding your last comment it seems you KNOW what you want, and that is not only "less than 3 length"

Answer (score 0):

For now your have `3-length` fragment because of these 3:

```
range(frame - 1, n - 2, 3 ) and sequenza[i:i+3]
                        ^                    ^
```

So to get a different size, change it

```
def codone(sequenza, frame, frag_size):
    n = len(sequenza)

    for i in range(frame - 1, n - 2, frag_size):
        yield sequenza[i:i + frag_size]


test = list(range(20))
print(list(codone(test, 1, 2)))
# [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17]]
print(list(codone(test, 1, 3)))
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
print(list(codone(test, 1, 4)))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19]]
```